# Apache Rewrite problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

1. http://www.a.com/content/1
2. http://www.a.com/content/seo-text-1

   RewriteRule ^content/(\d+)|.+?-(\d+)    action/index.php?id=$2

This rule don't work `second url`, How to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for any reason you need to have it in single rule, you can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)-?(\d+)$ action/index.php?id=$2 [R]
```

But more readable solution is to use two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^content/(\d+)$ action/index.php?id=$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^content/.*-(\d+)$ action/index.php?id=$1 [R]
```